# Changing Pen Color when plotting data in Visual Basic 6, when using MSChart

Tags: vb6

I plot measured data in MSChart using a call to the subroutine listed below.  I want to plot this data using a red trace, by turning the pen color to red.  What must I add to the subroutine code in order to plot the data trace in red?

```
    Private Sub Channel_2(Points2, dTime2, dData2)

       Dim rows2 As Long
       Dim i2 As Long
       Agt54600Scope1.GetWaveformData 2, Points2, dTime2, dData2
       rows2 = UBound(dData2, 1)
       ReDim data2(rows2, 1)

   For i2 = 1 To rows2
       data2(i2, 0) = dTime2(i2)
       data2(i2, 1) = dData2(i2)
    Next i2

   With MSChart2   
        .Plot.Axis(VtChAxisIdX).CategoryScale.Auto = False
        .Plot.Axis(VtChAxisIdX).CategoryScale.DivisionsPerTick = Points2 / 10
        .Plot.Axis(VtChAxisIdX).CategoryScale.DivisionsPerLabel = Points2 + 1
        .Plot.SeriesCollection(1).Position.Excluded = True
        .chartType = VtChChartType2dLine
        .ChartData = data2

     End With

   End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tested it, but the below should help you. Refer the [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263342(v=vs.60).aspx)

```
With MSChart2
    .Plot.Axis(VtChAxisIdX).CategoryScale.Auto = False
    .Plot.Axis(VtChAxisIdX).CategoryScale.DivisionsPerTick = Points2 / 10
    .Plot.Axis(VtChAxisIdX).CategoryScale.DivisionsPerLabel = Points2 + 1
    .Plot.SeriesCollection(1).Position.Excluded = True
    .chartType = VtChChartType2dLine
    .ChartData = data2
    .RandomFill = False
    With .Plot
        'Below will set your line color
        With .SeriesCollection(1)
            With .Pen
                .Width = ScaleX(1, vbPixels, vbTwips)
                .VtColor.Set 255, 0, 0  'give the color of your choice here
            End With
        End With
    End With
End With
```